# How to display an rgb image in a RGB colour cube in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rgb

So I have a RGB image and I want to display it in a RGB colour cube with its pixels as points in the colour cube. It sounds simple but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `img` is a MxNx3 image, you can do it like this:

```
[M, N, ~] = size(img);
plot3(...
    reshape(img(:,:,1), 1, M * N), ...
    reshape(img(:,:,2), 1, M * N), ...
    reshape(img(:,:,3), 1, M * N), '.')
xlabel('Red'), ylabel('Green'), zlabel('Blue')
grid on
```

Comment: Is the `...` meant to written as that itself? Or do you expect me to fill in something in its place?

Comment: The `...` is how you tell Matlab the command continues on the next line. I just used them to make the plot call more clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the axis box on to simulate a cube, and do a 3D scatter plot:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
vRGB = reshape(I,[],3);

plot3(vRGB(:,1),vRGB(:,2),vRGB(:,3),'.','MarkerSize',0.5)
set(gca,'Box','on')
xlabel('red'); ylabel('green'); zlabel('blue');
xlim([0 255]); ylim([0 255]); zlim([0 255])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the result given by the other answer (by Rafael) is closer to what I wanted.